# Xceed DataGrid SelectedItem issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed, xceed-datagrid

In my project I have an Xceed data grid which is bound to a data source with many records and record details. I am attempting to create a context menu option that will allow the user to search for a specific detail in a specific column. While I have successfully completed the functionality there is a UI part that is giving me some trouble, in that when I select the row in C#, if that row is not in view the row is never focused on. Thus the user has to scroll up and down looking for the row with expanded details.

I am able to set the SelectedRow and expand the details like so:

```
this.grid.AutoFilterValues[userColumn].Clear();
this.grid.AutoFilterValues[userColumn].Add(userValue);
if (this.creditLinesDataGridControl.Items.Count > 0)
{
    this.grid.SelectedItem = this.grid.Items[0];
    this.grid.ExpandDetails(this.grid.Items[0]);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value not found in column: " + userColumn);
}
this.grid.AutoFilterValues[userColumn].Clear();
```

where userColumn and userValue are set previously in the method.

How can I make the grid focus on the row after I've set the SelectedItem and expanded the details?

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the Xceed DataGrid's API, but typically such classes provide a method like `ScrollIntoView(...)`. After googling a bit, I found that Xceed's DataGrid obviously offers a method called `BringItemIntoView(...)`. Did you try that one?
For example, in [this thread](http://xceed.com/CS/forums/thread/18052.aspx) in the Xceed forum they discuss this method.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I guess when I was reading the methods for the Xceed DataGrid I just overlooked that one. Thank you very much.

Comment: Addition: I had to add a call to `UpdateLayout()` first, before calling `BringItemIntoView()`.